# How to correctly add dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven

Here is the current structure of my project (dependencies in POM)

```
- commons

- generator
  -> dependencies: commons

- database
  -> dependencies: commons, generator

- statemachine
  -> dependencies: commons, database

- server
  -> dependencies: commons, statemachine, database, generator
```

It's obvious which depends on which. But there is the redundancy I don't like. If I changed one version, I would have to change it everywhere.

So the better (for me) solution may be this

```
- commons

- generator
  -> commons

- database
  -> generator

- statemachine
  -> database

- server
  -> statemachine
```

This is much more simple. On the other hand, you can't see the real structure, you have to use effective POM (if you have this option in IDE).

So my question is: which approach is better and why? Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should declare those dependencies you need directly, whenever you make use of code or API of e.g. "commons" you should have this dependency in your POM. Otherwise when a  transitive dependency you rely on will be removed, you'll have several problems for already released versions.

The version problems is "solved" by [dependency mediation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste, actually. I agree that the second approach is easier but personally I think that the first approach is better since it gives clearer picture of your project dependencies structure.

If this is a multi-module project and all of the above are project modules that share the same version, then you can simply declare dependencies as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep each project's dependencies as minimal as possible, but how to do so depends:

If the dependencies are *my* projects, then assuming a hierarchical chain makes more sense, because I'm in control of which projects rely on what, and it's more likely I'd be fairly vigilant when defining versions across the "aggregate" of the projects.

If the dependencies *aren't* my projects, IMO it makes more sense to list them individually. This provides finer-grained version control, and allows the project defining them greater leeway rather than be forced to keep whatever version was already defined.

*(Dependencies can always be manually excluded or included in top-level dependencies.)*